# parentheses around import ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm learning React Native, just curious about the parentheses in the first line of import

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello world</Text>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorldApp', () => HelloWorldApp);
```

Why wrap Component with `{}` but not React?

Comment: It's because it's exported as default, see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import)

Comment: @ivarni if it's default why even mention there?

Comment: huh? the variable it gets imported into has to have a name. Just doing `import from 'react'` wouldn't make any sense and probably counts as a syntax error. I suggest spending some time reading about the ES6 module system.

Answer (score 4):

`React` is the *default* export (there can only be one of these per module). Default exports can be imported like this:

```
import React from "react";
```

`Component` is a *named* export (there can be many of these). Named exports are imported like this:

```
import { Component } from "react";
```

What you're seeing is both of these things imported on the same line.

`default` exports aren't automatically available everywhere, so they still need importing.

Note that the reason `React` needs importing at all is because of the way that JSX is transformed into JS - `React` needs to be available so `<Text>` can be transformed into `React.createElement(Text, ...`.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that Component is classified as a `named export`, so you can have multiple named exports from a single file but only one default export

Comment: @deowk I've edited to add that detail - let me know what you think.

Comment: looking gooood...;)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a matter of shorting the next invocations, since Component is a subclass of React, so that way you use React as default with all it has in it. and Component as a single class you'd use. By the way you use braces in import when you want something specific as a method or class, that is named export. There's a better explanation in here. 
[Having both named exports and a default export in a module](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Navbar';

export default class MyNavbar extends React.Component {
    render(){
      return (
        <Navbar className="navbar-dark" fluid>
        ...
        </Navbar>
      );
    }
}
```